# How to get the company id from Linkedin Company URL in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, linkedin-api

I have the Linkedin company URL as follows,

```
http://in.linkedin.com/company/abb
```

and the company ID for ABB limited is `277579`. Essentially you can also reach ABB through `http://www.linkedin.com/company/277579`.

But if I have only `http://in.linkedin.com/company/abb`. Is it possible to get the company ID through this URL? Does parsing the URL help? Seeking any good method to get the company ID.

Is there any other way to do without using Linkedin API?

Hope I am clear with my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/apis See Companies section

Comment: @Dr.Dan thanks. can you help me on how to implement it on PHP?

Comment: Googling `how to use the linkedin api php` will give plenty of good starting points.

Comment: @Pekka Is linkedin API paid one? It says unauthorized usage all the time.

Comment: Did you register your app? https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide

Comment: @Pekka No. I dont want to. Its Like I am wondering whether we can parse the result of 'http://in.linkedin.com/company/abb' to get the company ID.

Comment: No. The API is the only way for a PHP app to get information from linkedin. Like most such sites, they are protecting their data from bots ripping it without permission.

Answer (score 4):

Type in your company name in the autocomplete field.  Wait until your company name appears as a result. Then click on your company name.  Click on Get Code.

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="162479" data-counter="top"></script>
```

e.g. `data-id="162479"` is the ID for Apple Company Page

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to get this with PHP, so programmatically discovering a company's id may not be an option this way.

However, if you set up a MITM between yourself and LinkedIn.com, you can discover all the network activity between your browser and LinkedIn. A quick way to do this is is by using https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAP or http://mitmproxy.org/.

LinkedIn sends the company id of any company page you visit to their ad partners at doubleclick. An example request I discovered is:

> https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/linkedin.dart/biz-overview;optout=false;lang=en;tile=2;sz=300x250;s=0;v=6;u=jDh5sSdmpllmbkt1lndQdCt7;mod=950;title=ic;func=cre;func=edu;coid=744212;coid=2408664;ind=69;ind=80;csize=c;csize=d;occ=290;occ=294;occ=382;pocc=82;pocc=41;pocc=10;zip=20009;cntry=us;reg=97;sub=0;con=j;edu=19947;gy=2011;deg=400;dgcls=200;gdr=m;age=23;seg=773;seg=805;seg=546;seg=1039;seg=683;seg=535;seg=682;seg=1048;seg=748;seg=543;seg=9001;grp=122208;grp=49362;grp=3981403;grp=40456;grp=2229435;sjt=627;sjt=517;sjt=75;fos=100173;fos=100189;company=1273631;tile_p=2;adsuite=v2.2.5-min;sfadapter=t;ord=4824126317418

Within the request parameters, find the "company" param, and its value should be the numeric company id you need:

> company=1273631

To verify it is the correct company id, tack it onto the end of a LinkedIn company page:

> https://www.linkedin.com/company/1273631

Voila, it works!

Answer (score 3):

You can download the content of site and find

`encodeURIComponent('company=12345')`

which appears to be valid company id. Just parse it to get ID.

Answer (score 2):

a simple way would be to do a file_get_contents on the company page to get the html source and look for "company%3D" and grab the number between that and the next "%"

Comment: just noticed this question is two years old. sorry.

Comment: this works well too, much better for a programmatic implementation

Answer (score 1):

Why not just hover over the 'follow'/'unfollow' of the company/showcase page, this shows the id in the url ?

Or have I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
      api_key: [API KEY]
    </script>       
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function onGetSuccess(data) {
            console.log(data);              
            for(var i in data.values){
                document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = data.values[i].name + " / " + data.values[i].id;
            }               
        }
        function onError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }           
        function GetCompanyLinkedIn() {
            var url = "/companies/?/updates/format=json&is-company-admin=true";
            IN.API.Raw(url)     
            .method("GET")
            .result(onGetSuccess)
            .error(onError);            
        }           
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div >          
        <script type="IN/Login">
            Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>
            <p id="company" >
                <button type="button" onclick="GetCompanyLinkedIn()">Get company id('s)</button>
            </p>                    
        </script>                   
    </div>      
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that Andrew's solution worked.
Inside the page source, there are multiple scripts with a company%3... data attribute with the company ID; mine was not visible since the URL was customized.

Answer (score 0):

1. View page source by pressing ctrl(command)+alt(option/shift)+c
2. search the page source by pressing ctrl(cmd) + f
3. input "**urn:li:fsd_company:**" in the search section and normally the first match will give the company's id(if not,refresh the page)

Answer (score -1):

Hover over the follow button on your company page. https://www.linkedin.com/company/follow/submit?id=6667854&fl=stop&ft=0_Y3kiyf

The ID "6667854"

It works as I followed my company page from another site where it's implemented.

Comment: he was actually looking for a way to do this in PHP automatically.

Answer (score -1):

try .htaccess file and type the following line

```
rewriterule ^http://in.linkedin.com/company/abb http://www.linkedin.com/company/277579
```