# LinkedIn API: Company URL -> Company ID

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a way to translate a company's LinkedIn URL to its Company ID in an automated, repeatable and reliable manner?

e.g. https://www.linkedin.com/company/bbc -> 1762

Official API documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_profile) assumes that the ID is already known.

Scraping of company pages is not a suitable solution as LinkedIn actively discourages this and could block the activity with no notice. I am looking to be a good citizen and use API as designed.

I am aware of the answers to this question: [Linkedin API - get company ID from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317055/linkedin-api-get-company-id-from-url). However, these do not provide a solution which is automated.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like it, which is surprising.